# What is the right construct for this expression?

Tags: phrase-usage

> Is there anything from whose perspective, this thing can be good.

I would like to know if this expression sounds right to natives? I think grammatically it is right, but it seems a little unnatural.

What would be the right construct for this expression?

Answer (score 10):

It certainly does not sound natural.  Grammatically, the comma needs to be deleted, and a question mark must replace the period.

A simpler, more natural rephrase would be *Is there any perspective from which this could be considered beneficial/positive?*

Answer (score 7):

Or, to keep more inline with the original sentence, you could say:

> Is there any perspective from which this could be considered a good thing?

This makes it a little more "chatty", which is good, especially if you're using the word *thing*.